# Why I'm not getting any output differential when toggling my RTS pin on my RS232 port?

Tags: linux, serial-port

I'm trying to turn on/off a output or switch a relay etc by controlling the RTS or DTR pin of my RS232 signal. I've created a script in C that switches my DTR or RTS flag on/off but I'm not getting any difference in my output on my serial port to terminal adapter(see image below):

[image]

The structure of my RS232 is as follows:

[image]

As the image describes, the RTS signal is on pin 8, when I flag this to "on" and i measure between pin 1(ground) and pin 8(RTS) im getting 3V. When I switch it back to off it remains staying at 3V, so nothing changed when I'm toggling DTR or RTS.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've tried the code below(I think it matches @Vincent Achard's answer). This does not work, when I measure between pin 1(ground) and pin 6(5v output) this remains 5V while running the script. Also when I measure between pin 1(ground) and ping 8(RTS) this remains 2.8V while running the script. Does anyone see any mistakes in this code?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well if you can switch your dtr, just plug that to the signal in of your relay.

Comment: I can set my DTR signal high or low and confirm this by checking it, however this will not give me any signals on the output of my serial port. Pin 1-6 stays 5V(supply, see document) and pin1-8(RTS) gives me 3V.

Comment: How can you set your DTR signal high and low (and checking it) without having any signal on the pin? I misunderstand particularly the checking part, which I consider being able to turn on a LED. If you cannot turn on a LED, how do you check that your DTR pin reacts to your code?

Comment: Sorry, its my RTS pin. But i check this pin in code, its pin 8 if u see the documentation link. I connect to my ttyO0 first, then i set the pin by using tiocmbis, i check using tiocmget than i use tiocmbic to set it to 0 and i check again. Output of my script: set high -> check(is high) -> set low -> check(is low). However the output on my pins are all the same everytime i check, pin 1-6 is 5V and pin 1-8 is always 3V.

Comment: OK. So please reformat your post, this is misleading: "I've created a script in C that switches my DTR signal": if the voltage is the same, it does not switch your signal. And the most relevant part of your question is your ioctl C code versus the voltage result you get. Starting there, we will be able to better help you as it will lye in the scope of 'linux serial port programming'. (The HMI part is irrelevant, it could be a cheap usb to serial dongle, the question would be the same).

Comment: Great. Now: your code. I guess you use something like ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &ctl); where ctl looks like TIOCM_DTR or TIOCM_RTS ? Correct me if I'm wrong. (And it would be great to have your code in the post it would help). If this is the case, what is your fd?

Comment: I see you use tiocmbis. I don't know it well but from what i read in your comment, your problem might be the device you are connecting to. It should be a (node)/(special file) like /dev/ttyUSB0 or so, that represents your serial port device to the kernel. /dev/tty0 might not be the right node.

Comment: Its ttyO0 which is linked to ttyS0, I tested this with my scope. I wrote data to this port to test it with my oscilloscope.

Comment: @VincentAchard I deleted my code on accident, I only got the .exe.. But yeah i connect to my ttyO0 which is linked to my ttys0. I check if connection is set and if connection is set I set the DTR or RTS flag on with TIOCMBIS. After that I check if the flag is set by using TIOCMGET and when its set I set it back off with TIOCMBIC.

Comment: I used to do that using ioctls: fd=open(dev,O_RDWR); ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &controlbits); sleep(1); close(fd); From my notes it seems consistent with what you get: without the sleep(1) the pin would go to its default level (3V). There was a trick on the circuit: I did not use a regular relay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DTR and RST pins on a serial interface do not act like GPIOs: their level will not stay high or down.

I could override this behavior by modifying the kernel tty driver to get a permanent non default state:

file: 
drivers/tty/tty_port.c

in the

```
function tty_port_shutdown()
```

replace

```
tty_port_lower_dtr_rts(port);
```

by

```
tty_port_raise_dtr_rts(port);
```

maybe some easier solutions exist???

Comment: Give me one second to try this, looks awesome!

Comment: This code gives me a "Segmentation fault"

Comment: Look the updated post, I think this matches the code u written right? Sorry I cant copy from my VM somehow, therefore i took screenshot.

Comment: Yes it matches. You get a segfault at which point?

Comment: I fixed the segmentation fault. The code I updated in my post works fine but I'm not getting any difference in my outputs when i measure between these :(pin1 -> pin6) or (pin1 -> pin8) while running the code.

Comment: Could it be some tty setting? I wonder why you use the noctty flag?

Comment: From another tutorial, this is my first week with Linux. Let me try without ctty flag? Rest of settings are correct?

Comment: OK really sorry I did not read my notes correctly... I had to modify the kernel driver to get a permanent switch... Might be a little hard to recompile a kernel in your case?

Comment: On linux, just opening a serial tty (eg. with `exec 7</dev/ttyS0`) will raise the DTR / RTS lines, and closing it (`exec 7<&-`) will lower them. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543527/308316). No need for any C program. For that to work, the port should of course be really be a RS-232, no RS-422/485 or something else (many devices can change it on the fly). And the OP should be poking at the right hole -- eg my phone has 3 serial interfaces, and only one leads to the 3.5mm headphones jack ;-)

Comment: @VincentAchard I try this solution, give me a moment

Comment: The code u u wrote looks like c, in both maps "driver" and "drivers" are not any files who end with .c. My kernel version is 3.10.12 btw

Comment: @NielsStenden the voltages you get don't look like your port is a rs-232 / is in rs-232 mode. If it were and `ttyO0` really were your serial port, this simple shell command would raise _both_ DTR and RTS and lower them after 3 seconds: `exec 7</dev/ttyO0; sleep 3; exec 7<&-`. See also my comment above.

Comment: Any luck? Maybe you should buy a cheap usb to serial to do some tests on a /dev/ttyUSB that is known to work. They cost 5US$ only.